# VNH5019 Motor Driver reverse polarity protection

Tags: motor, driver

So I managed to fry one of these drivers. It was rather simple - It was end of the day, and I plugged the power supply in reverse polarity (24V), and it blew up.

Now, I wondered - How come there is no reverse polarity protection? Turns out there is, but only up until 16V. However, the maximum recommended input voltage of the chip is specified to be 24V, saying it can survive up to 41V. Anything above 24V produces over voltage protection to shut it down.

They even call the design "robust". https://www.pololu.com/product/1451

Is this design indeed "robust" or considered good, if it provides reverse polarity protection only up to 16V, although people may operate it at higher voltages? Would it not make sense to protect against reverse polarity at least within the specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the reverse protection FET is an [AON6508](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AON6508.pdf) configured per Figure 4 in the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vnh5019a-e.pdf). This FET should be good for 24V operation (it's rated at 30V). Not sure why the limitation on reverse voltage. ST's own [evaluation board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/eval-vnh5019-p1.html),  that this appears to be copied from, makes no mention of that.